ETA On CIS v2.0.0 For Canonical Ubuntu 22.04 Pro LTS Via Ubuntu Advantage (pro/usg)
Asking on the availability or ETA when CIS v2.0.0 (https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/ubuntu_linux) will be expressed in the Ubuntu Advantage agent (“pro” and its enabled “usg”)?
Particularly for Ubuntu 22.04 Pro LTS?  I see that CIS v1.0.0 has been used and noted for 22.04 LTS, at https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/usg/cis, likely for a long time or a few years.  If there’s a website or location for progress, that would also be helpful.
Any help or ETA for this request would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Wrong place to ask. the volunteers here do not work for the company and have no idea on things like that.
